# How to use image search api [BING]

Tags: javascript, ajax, bing

I'm trying to use Image Search API, but do not get the search results.
 This was the code I found on the same page of documentation.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = {
            // Request parameters
            "q": "cats",
            "count": "10",
            "offset": "0",
            "mkt": "en-us",
            "safeSearch": "Moderate",
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","MYKEY");
            },
            type: "GET",
            // Request body
            data: "{body}",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I really want to do image searches, and with this API is that it can serve me.

Comment: `data: "{body}"` doesn't look right - do you have a link to the page you got this code from?

Comment: url is [link]https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43eeccf5ff8098cef3807/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d [/link] I try with ˋconsole.log(data)ˋ without result

Comment: weird how you need this `"{body}"` in every language except C# ... any errors or messages on the console

Answer (score 0):

Jaromanda X is right, you can remove `{body}` and it should work. I'm using the same code and it works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = {
            // Request parameters
            "q": "cats"
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","MYKEY");
            },
            type: "GET",
            // Request body
            data: "",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```